# java program that takes a value from user and converts it to its octal equivalent

Tags: java

So i'm trying to build a program that takes user input and then if that input is between 0 and 2097151, then the program will convert that int to it's octal equivalent and then displays it at the end. The program I have posted below WORKS just fine, but probably isn't efficient, I'm curious and am trying to find help on how to implement this same program using a while loop using counter controlled repetition, as that was suggested as the method to use but I'm not seeing how to do that.

the question I'm asking myself and am confused about is: How do I continue to divide a number by 8, continue to take the modulus of a number by 8, and store that modulus into separate variables so that I can print them out right next to each other? I'm unsure how to keep taking the modulus until my number reaches 0 and keep track of the remainders using a while loop.

and to clarify, this is a school assignment, and is limited to while loops, for loops, logical operators and if/if else statements. I cannot use methods, or built in methods to achieve the desired end result.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class kwatke_OctalConversion {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int modulus1, modulus2, modulus3, modulus4, modulus5, modulus6, modulus7;
        int smallest=0;
        int Largest=2097151;
        System.out.println("The purpose of this program is to take a value from the "
            + "user and\n convert it from a base 10 number to a base 8 number and "
            + "display it\n for the user to see the converted octal number\n"
            + "Please enter a non-negative number between 0 and 2097151 to see it's "
            + "octal equivalent: " );
        int number = input.nextInt();
        if (number<smallest || number>Largest) {
            System.out.println ( "UNABLE TO CONVERT" );
        } else {
            modulus1 = (number % 8); //meat of our program, take number from user,
            number /= 8;             // take modulus of number, divide by 8, rinse and
            modulus2 = (number % 8); // repeat storing the modulus in a differnt var
            number /= 8;             // each time and continusing to divide the
            modulus3 = (number % 8); // leftover number by 8 until it reaches 0,
            number /= 8;             // storing modulus in a new variable each time.
            modulus4 = (number % 8);
            number /= 8;
            modulus5 = (number % 8);
            number /= 8;
            modulus6 = (number % 8);
            number /= 8;
            modulus7 = (number % 8);

            System.out.printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n", modulus7, modulus6, modulus5,
                modulus4, modulus3, modulus2, modulus1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number : ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    String result = Integer.toOctalString(number);
```

[See the source code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toUnsignedString%28int%2Cint%29)

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
    int i=0;
    int a[] = new int[100];
    while (number>0) {
       a[i] = number % 8;
       number = number / 8;
       i++;
    }

    for(int j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
       System.out.printf("%d", a[j]);
    }
```

As suggested in the comments, you can also use recursion to find the octal number. You can adapt it to accept and validate user input.

```
class OctalNumbers
{
    static int a[] = new int[100];
    static int index = 0;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int number = 56;
        findOctal(number);
        for(int j = index-1; j>=0; j--) {
            System.out.printf("%d", a[j]);
        }
    }

    private static void findOctal(int number) {

        if(number != 0) {
            int rem = number % 8;
            a[index] = rem;
            number = number / 8;
            index++;
            findOctal(number);  
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: int j = i-1; should help

Comment: I'll bet he was looking for the recursive approach. This work exactly the same. Beat me to it. Good job.

Comment: I appreciate the input but as I stated above due to "requirements" I am only allowed to use basic concepts like a while loop, if statements and grabbing input. I am NOT allowed to use recursion, nor arrays,  nor methods, nor can I use anything prebuilt into java language so the following can't be used in my program:  String result = Integer.toOctalString(number)

Comment: so you cannot even store a result in a string and print it in reverse?